# Can you suspend an offline audio context on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api, audiocontext

[The browser compatibility table for `OfflineAudioContext.suspend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext/suspend) has an empty cell for Firefox, which is quite confusing.

It works fine in Chrome. I still think that `OfflineAudioContext.suspend` is currently implemented in Firefox (v51.0.1), because I'm able to call the method. My problem is that whenever I call this method, I get:

```
DOMException [NotSupportedError: "Operation is not supported"
code: 9
nsresult: 0x80530009
location: http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:13603]
```

This is the order of the two main calls

```
offlineContext.suspend(0).then(() => ..., e => console.log(e))
offlineContext.startRendering()
```

`console.log(e)` prints the error message above, so it does not go into the success callback of the `then`.

I have tried modifying the "suspendTime" param of the `suspend` method, placing the call after the `startRendering` method, with no success.

Is it actually supposed to work in Firefox? I think it would be weird that they allow us to call the method, but make it fail all the time.

Comment: A fresh audio context is extremely cheap ... Suggested wisdom is to avoid pause instead kill and get a new context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Firefox hasn't gotten around to implementing this feature for an offline context. (I think suspend is supported of an online audio context, though).